# Get final 2 data in json_encode output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm bring json_encode data. The output looks as below

```
[{"ab":"item1"},{"ab":"item2"},{"ab":"item3"},{"tg":"int1"},{"int":"int2"}]
```

I fetch the data as

```
$.post('add.php',
    { },
    function(data){ 
       var tot = data.length-2;
       for(i = 1; i<tot; i++){
           console.log( data[i].ab ) //ab data fetched here
       }
    }
);
```

My question is, how do I get the final 2 data (referred as `int1` and `int2` in my example above)?

NOte: The data length varies

Comment: will the object in array be always only one key and value ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla yes the format will remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lastTwo = data.slice(data.length - 2);
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metyx549/)**</kbd>

If you don't know the *key* of those objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lastTwo.length; i++)
{
    var a = Object.keys(lastTwo[i]);
    var value = lastTwo[i][a[0]];
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metyx549/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: It would be `lastTwo[0].tg` and `lastTwo[1].int` in your case.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown What if `tg` and `int` are not fixed, keys are something else like `foo`, `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) twice, to get the last two items.

```
var data = [{"ab":"item1"},{"ab":"item2"},{"ab":"item3"},{"tg":"int1"},{"int":"int2"}];

var last = data.pop(),
    secondLast = data.pop();

// As keys of the object are not fixed, use Object.keys
var lastItem = last[Object.keys(last)[0]];
var secondLastItem = secondLast[Object.keys(secondLast)[0]];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3r858kke/)

Comment: What if some day OP wants to get last 10 items? 10x `.pop()` ?